# Update multiple rows with 2 parameter in 1 column in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem with updating record. I want to update 2 record in 1 column in one button click with two parameters. this is the code :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int use = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

        perintahsql = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Barang SET Pakai = @Pakai WHERE Nama_Barang = 'Mie Rebus' AND Nama_Barang = 'Telor'", koneksi);
        perintahsql.Parameters.Clear();
        perintahsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pakai", use);
    }
```

How to overcome this problem? Thanks.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your SQL statement to:

```sql
UPDATE Barang SET Pakai = @Pakai WHERE Nama_Barang in ('Mie Rebus', 'Telor')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clause is looking for rows where `Nama_Barang = 'Mie Rebus' AND Nama_Barang = 'Telor'`

The key is the AND here. You don't have any rows where Nama_Barang is **both** 'Mie Rebus' and 'Telor'. You're looking for rows where Nama_Barang is either 'Mie Rebus' **or** 'Telor', so your WHERE clause should be `Nama_Barang = 'Mie Rebus' OR Nama_Barang = 'Telor'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the AND to an OR operator in the WHERE clause.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int use = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

    perintahsql = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Barang SET Pakai = @Pakai WHERE Nama_Barang = 'Mie Rebus' OR Nama_Barang = 'Telor'", koneksi);
    perintahsql.Parameters.Clear();
    perintahsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pakai", use);
}
```

However, if you're going to be doing this for many values then its probably best to use

> WHERE Nama_Barang IN ('name1','name2', ... ,'name99')